Paginated report dynamic schedule
I am building a paginated report in powerbi but stuck in schedule part. The report should be sent the 1st day of each month with last month data   ex: 01/09 a report should be sent with data of 01/08 to 31/08
i have a analyst service as source and create a table which take all the date of the past month but unfortunately cannot able to make a relationship

Not sure what the actual problem is? What does "cannot able to make a relationship" mean? If English is an issue, in the world of AI, use it to format your question so we can help!

It sounds like you want 2 date parameters that default to the first and last days of the previous month and add a filter to the query using them.  End of last month is =TODAY.AddDays(0 - TODAY.Day)
